# binding specific data to the url

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to bind the id from a row to the `href` output. that is getting a `url something?id=***` in order to use `$_GET` and bring the id on the next page.

I need to be the `id` on the same row that is clicked on a table I'm displaying.

If I try to bind it by stating `href=" wahtever?id=<php echo $row['id'] ?>` the id will return as empty. If I  use a loop it works but give me all the id's on the table.

I tried different solutions I found on internet like stating `echo '<td> <a href="****?id='.$row['id'].' </a></td>'` or making a new selection using php code on the href link... nothing seems to work.

I'm confused, how can I make a link on a table that will include the id of the clicked row?

My code looks like this now:

```
    <td bgcolor="#FAB1CA"><a href="view_topic.php?id=<?php $sql="SELECT * FROM forum_question ORDER BY id DESC";
                                                           $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result){
                                                           echo $rows['ID'] ;  ?>">
```

Just to make it clearer, it is a simple table displaying 4 columns with different data using a loop, the first column is the id and the second one would be the topic, where I trying to build the links.

Comment: Are you trying to display information based on a single id?

Comment: `$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);`  then `<?php echo $rows; ?>` in your `href`.

Comment: Where are you fetching the results? Please separate your SQL from the link. Store the ID in a variable instead.

Comment: jddev81, no, I have several id's, one for each row. the second column will have the links and the first one the id numbers. what I need is to senf the id number for the clicked row into the url to bring info in the next page based on that id. Raylene's solution sounds pretty logic, I will give it a try.

Comment: @EstebanLuques See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have 5 columns in a database table and you want to show them on the page, and link the topic cell to the topic page and pass the id of that topic.

I cleaned your code up a little and gave an example of how to do that. Keep in mind, I'm using an associative array so you'll need to be sure it matches what the columns are called in your database.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Topic</th>
        <th>Answers</th>
        <th>Views</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $sql="SELECT * FROM forum_question ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        while($row = myslqi_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>

        <tr>

            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>

            <td bgcolor="#FAB1CA">
                <a href="view_topic.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];  ?>">
                    <?php echo $row['topic']; ?>
                </a>
            </td>

            <td><?php echo $row['answers']; ?></td>

            <td><?php echo $row['views']; ?></td>

            <td><?php echo $row['theDate']; ?></td>

        </tr>



        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: I tried that but it will return the link as view_topic.php?id="" ... what I'm trying to say is that the GET function will result in a empty query.

Comment: and yes its a forum app, and the table have 5 columns, ID, TOPIC, VIEWS, ANSWERS and DATE/TIME. I'm making a diferent query to show each column values, all ordered by the same SELECT query. the links work just fine, but the part after the ?id= is left in blank. if I make a loop with a new while will give all the id's, but if I use it as you suggested, the id is left blank.

Comment: @EstebanLuques is the column in the database called 'id'?

Comment: And to say something about the previous comment... You don't need to make a query for each column. It would be best to make this one query and wrap it around all of your `tr`s. I'm not sure why this would be blank here. Right after the while loop opens var_dump $row and tell me what you have.

Comment: @EstebanLuques see my updated answer and tell me if that's the sort of table you are laying out here. If so, this code should work once you make sure  the column names are correct.

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see `$row variable` in your code
you can use `myslqi_fetch_assoc` for get $row variable
i think this answer its true

```
        <?php
    $sql="SELECT * FROM forum_question ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    ?>
    <td bgcolor="#FAB1CA"><a href="view_topic.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>go to view_topic</a></td>
    <?php
 }
    ?>
```

Comment: yes a made the mysqli_fetch_assoc() it just doesnt appeat there because is before that line,

Comment: You need to pass the result in the mysqli_fetch_assoc() function.